# Excel Macro: Use Column A Cell Value as prefix of downloaded file for that row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

This macro downloads the files I need from the web using a url found in columns C and D for multiple rows.  However, it adds the value of cell A1 as the prefix of every filename downloaded.

I need help modifying my macro so that instead of using Cell $A$1 as the prefix to every file downloaded, I want it to use the value in Column "A" of the same row.

```
Dim URL As String
Dim LocalFileName As String
Dim B As Boolean
Dim ErrorText As String
Dim C As Range
Dim sTxt As String
sTxt = Cells(1, "a").Value
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("C:D").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
For Each C In Range("C1:D" & Lastrow)
    If Len(C) > 0 Then
        URL = C.Text
'        LocalFileName = "C:\downloaded\" & Range("A1") & " " & Evaluate("TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(""" & C.Text & """,""/"",REPT("" "",1000)),1000))")
        B = DownloadFile(UrlFileName:=URL, _
                         DestinationFileName:=LocalFileName, _
                         Overwrite:=DoNotOverwrite, _
                         ErrorText:=ErrorText)
        If B = True Then
            Debug.Print "Download successful"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Download unsuccessful: " & ErrorText
        End If
    End If
Next C
End Sub
```

Example Data:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   12345   Record1 http://www.test.com/picture1.jpg    http://www.test.com/file1.pdf
2   abcde   Record2 http://www.test.com/Picture2.jpg    http://www.test.com/file2.pdf
```

In the above example, the desired filenames would then be:
-12345 picture1.jpg
-12345 file1.pdf
-abcde picture2.jpg
-abcde file2.pdf

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `C.Row` in place of `1`:

```
LocalFileName = "C:\downloaded\" & Range("A" & C.Row) & " " & Evaluate("TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(""" & C.Text & """,""/"",REPT("" "",1000)),1000))")
```